# Disable Aero Themes for a ClickOnce application

Tags: windows-7, compatibility, clickonce

I have an application that is deployed and installed using [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and on certain machines (mostly running Windows 7) I need to be able to disable Aero themes and possibly change other Compatibility Mode settings.

Right click -> Properties does not show the Compatibility tab...

[image]

... and the application is not listed in the Program Compatibility wizard in Control Panel.

Is there any other way to set up Compatibility Mode?

Comment: I am not able to create new categories so if someone wants to add a 'compatibility-mode' it would be more appropriate than 'compatibility'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is a way to natively disable visual themes during deployment, but this will enable the compatibility tab:

1. Open your project and go to the solution explorer.
2. If not already, enable the "Show All Files" setting (a button near the top of the Solution Explorer window that has an icon with three files on it).
3. Open your `App.manifest` file and go to this section:
   [image]
4. Uncomment lines 31, 35, and 46.
5. You should now be able to select compatibility mode (after rebuilding, of course.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  If possible I'd like to do this without needing to regenerate the manifest so I'll leave the question open to see if anyone else has an alternative suggestion

Comment: No problem, I understand. Also, if you run into an error while compiling, uncomment only line 31. There's an known bug in VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

```
reg.exe Add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\Program Files\YouInstallFolder\YourProgram.exe" /d"DISABLEDWM HIGHDPIAWARE"
```

(note: 32 bit app on an x64 system: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags)

Disable desktop composition **DISABLEDWM**
Disable display scaling on high DPI settings **HIGHDPIAWARE**

*Also:*

Run as Administrator **RUNASADMIN**
Windows 95 Mode **WIN95**
Windows 98 / Windows Me Mode **WIN98**
Windows NT 4.0 (Service Pack 5) Mode **NT4SP5**
Windows 2000 **WIN2000**
Windows XP (Service Pack 2) Mode **WINXPSP2**
Windows Server 2003 (Service Pack 1) **WINSRV03SP1**

There may be more - I can't seem to find a definitive list

Comment: The application is Deployed using ClickOnce so I don't have acces to the exe path (at least, not consistently)

Comment: I don't know if you could add the information to a `.reg` file and run that as part of the setup, or modify the registry during setup, or an initialization procedure (check if set, if not, add settings, and quit/re-run program) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763611/set-registry-key-through-clickonce-installation

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. Ideally I'd like to achieve this without releasing a new version though, so code/deployment changes are tricky!